# Filling in a square with custom sides

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, draw

I have the following code which produces the boundary of a square with each side labeled with a certain kind of arrow. I want to fill the interior with a color, but when I add "fill=color" as an argument, there is no change at all in the resulting image. How can I get this to work?

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
sep=2cm,
cells={shape=coordinate}
]
  \ar[draw=none,r, "{\tikz\node[rotate=270,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->](0,0);};  }" description]
  \ar[dash,r] 
& 
{} 
\\
  \ar[draw=none,r, "{\tikz\node[rotate=270,inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->](0,0)     ;};  }" description] 
  \ar[draw=none,u, "{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>](0,0) ;}; }" description] 
  \ar[dash,r] 
  \ar[dash,u] 
& 
{}
  \ar[draw=none,u, "{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt] {\tikz\draw[->>](0,0) ;}; }" description]
    \ar[dash,u]  
\end{tikzcd}.
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately your code nests `tikzpicture`s. Is there any reason why you want to use `tikz-cd` rather than just `tikz`?

Comment: @marmot No, I am not attached to this code at all. I just want the desired image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with fills and does not nest `tikzpicture`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[insert arrow/.style args={#1/#2}{postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{#2}}}}}]
 \draw[fill=blue!30,insert arrow/.list={0.125/>,0.37/>,0.38/>,0.625/<,0.87/<,0.88/<}] (0,0) -| ++ (2,2) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]